# How to understand the -min/-max options of !dumpheap in WinDBG SOS

Tags: windbg, sos

The documentation said it's used for limit the size of the output object, but based on my test, it's not what I expected:

```
0:000> !dumpheap -mt 000007fee12406a8 -max 400 -min 399
Address               MT     Size
000000000d1dc1f8 000007fee12406a8      936     
000000000d62bed8 000007fee12406a8     1016     
000000000d630d00 000007fee12406a8      984     
000000000d633aa8 000007fee12406a8      984     
000000000d65f368 000007fee12406a8      952     
000000000d685ff0 000007fee12406a8      952     
000000000d6b2150 000007fee12406a8      952
```

So how to understand the `-min` and `-max` options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WinDbg's default number format is hexadecimal. `0x400` is 1024 and `0x399` is 921, that explains the output. If you want decimal numbers, use the `0n` prefix, e.g. `0n400` and `0n399`.